# Discover Project's Associated Folder with REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, project-server

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 along with Project Server.

When we create a project via SP, it creates a Project and a Folder for documents of that project.

The thing is, if the name of the project is modified (e.g. from "project A" to "project B"), the folder name remains the same.

I'm using REST to access SP and PS, but in the PS endpoint doesn't seems to have such information about where the project`s files are stored.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by folder. Creating a project will create a SharePoint site, called the project workspace. The site has a document library and a few lists, such as the risks list. The site url is avilable via rest or [csom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.projectserver.client.project.projectsiteurl_di_pj14mref.aspx), and is alos in the reporting database.

In the reporting database, see the ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef field in the MSP_EpmProject_UserView view. Otherwise, see the ProjectSiteUrl field in either REST or CSOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This CSOM link is exactly what I'm trying to achieve! However, I'm not using CSOM, I'm using REST.. Is there a REST endpoint to that information?

Comment: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/projectdata/Projects. Look for ProjectWorkspaceInternalUrl